# WS2812B "Twitching"

Tags: ws2812b

I have a row of WS2812B on my PCB. I have 3 identical PCBs, and on 1 board the WS2812Bs are "twitching". They are showing colors just fine, but RGBs are flickering / twitching repeatedly. It happens very quickly but nonetheless very visible. Has anyone seen this issue in the past?

Comment: Did you decouple them properly?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes there is 0.1uF on every VCC.

Comment: I have not seen that before, and this is only a wild guess: maybe something is happening on the data line. If you have access to an oscilloscope it is easy enough to check.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. It has nothing to do with electrically.
My contract manufacturer flashed the MCU via ISP and in the process they changed the fuse bits. I have since reset the fuse bits to the default and it no longer exhibits this issue.

```
Default fuse bits:
L 0x5E
H 0x99
E 0xF3
LB 0x2C
```

This is quite puzzling nonetheless. I will update once I figure out the exact fuse bit that resulted in the random flicker.

Comment: What were the fuse bits set to?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry I am curious myself as well. I didn't get to save it.